# Console is throwing XML Parsing Errors when loading contents from one HTML file into another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml

I am using Firefox v123.0.1 (64-bit) to *locally* view the `index.html` for a static web page that I am developing, and I want to dynamically load the contents of another HTML file into a `<div>`. My goal with having several HTML files is to organize the contents of my web page so it is easier to maintain and to reduce the amount of data the client needs to load at once, all while not having to write duplicate code surrounding the `<div>` (e.g., by creating a web page for each `<div>` state).

When I write the contents directly into the `<div>`, I do not get XML Parsing Errors, but when I use jQuery 3.7.1 to load the contents from another HTML file, it has a problem with some void elements that are not explicitly closed like `<br>` instead of `<br/>` as well as some boolean attributes that are not explicitly defined like `hidden` instead of `hidden='true'`.

I would like to know:

1. How do I stop these errors from occurring?
2. Why do these errors happen?
3. Is there a better way to accomplish my original goal?

I wrote some code below to demonstrate this problem. The errors are detailed as comments. Notice that there are no errors when the contents originate from `index.html`, but for some unexpected reason, an error occurs when the same contents originate from `br.html` or `hidden.html`.

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css'>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button onclick='updateContainer("#container-with-br", "br.html");'>
      Load HTML containing &lt;br&gt;
    </button>
    <div id='container-with-br'>
      This HTML is from...<br>index.html
    </div>
    <!--
      XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </br>.
      Location: br.html:7:3
      Fixed by changing <br> to <br/>
    -->

    <br>

    <button onclick='updateContainer("#container-with-hidden", "hidden.html");'>
      Load HTML containing hidden element
    </button>
    <div id='container-with-hidden'>
      This HTML is from... index.html <span hidden>and this is hidden</span>
    </div>
    <!--
      XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
      Location: hidden.html:5:48
      Fixed by changing hidden to hidden='true'
    -->

    <script src='jquery-3.7.1.js'></script>
    <script>
      function updateContainer(container, filename) {
        $(container).load(filename);
      }
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

`br.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

  This HTML is from...<br>br.html

</html>
```

`hidden.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

  This HTML is from... hidden.html <span hidden>and this is hidden</span>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not have valid HTML.  The open and close tags are not symmetrical.  You cannot have angle brackets in the innertext without escaping the characters : This HTML is from...<br>index.html

Comment: @jdweng Could you elaborate? What does it mean for open and close tags to be symmetrical? And if I cannot have angle brackets in the innertext without escaping the characters, then why are there no errors when the same HTML originates from `index.html`?

Comment: If you are opening with a browser is may be using a different Content-Type which automatically escapes the special characters of GZIP is being used which encodes the special characters.  Any Meta Language must have every open angle bracket paired with a closing angle bracket.  See Wiki for handling special characters : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng If I escape the angle brackets in the other HTML files like `&lt;` and `&gt;`, then the web page displays `This HTML is from...<br>br.html`. I don't want to display the raw HTML on the web page. I still want it to be parsed as HTML code. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: All files are HTML which supports tags that don't have end tags _in HTML_. `index.html` is (presumably) parsed by the **HTML** parser of the browser. The loaded files appear to parsed by an **XML** parser provided by jQuery. My understanding is that  XML _does not support_ stand alone tags and requiries closing or self closing tags instead, as well as the use of XML's version of boolean attributes.. I suggest adding the code of `updateContainer` to the post - it looks to be quite relevant.

Comment: @traktor It was unclear why an XML parser was being used, but that does seem to be the case for some reason. `updateContainer` is in a `<script>` near the bottom of `index.html`.

Comment: @traktor Thanks! `updateContainer` is defined at the bottom of the `index.html` code block in my original post. Perhaps I was unclear, or I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: OOPS - my apologies,  this is entirely my misunderstand - I'll delete a preceding comment, but welcome to Stack Over is ongoing!

Comment: Back to the question however, HTML only really supports external HTML files by loading them into an iframe. If you want to develop more complex files that include head section code, you may not be able to load them properly by other means.

Comment: An end tag the name is optional but you need the forward slash  So you can have either <br/> or <br></br>

Comment: @traktor No worries! I think you are right that an `iframe` may be needed to avoid the XML parsing issues, and since I'd prefer not to use one on a simple static web page, I wonder if it would make more sense to put multiple `<div>`s for each desired `<div>` state into `index.html` and then hide/unhide them as needed. It just wouldn't be as neatly compartmentalized as having multiple HTML files. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @jdweng As I understand it, `<br>` actually _is_ valid HTML and does _not_ need a closing tag because it is a void element, but because the HTML is being fed through an XML parser for some reason, it produces an error because a closing tag is needed for it to be valid _XML_.

Comment: The issue seems to be that your server doesn't send the proper `"Content-Type"` for the fetched page. JQuery will thus apparently attempt to parse it as XML (not entirely sure where, it's basically in `$.ajax()`).  You could avoid that by fetching the resource yourself and then do what `$.load()` does under the hood: `fetch(filename).then((r) => r.ok?r.text():Promise.reject("Network Error")).then(t => $(container).html($.parseHTML(t)))`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the explanation. That aligns with some of the other explanations I saw before I posted this question. I tried updating `updateContainer` with your revised version of `$.load`, and it worked!

That said, I am not using a server; I am just opening `index.html` locally in Firefox as I develop the static web page. When I look in `jquery-3.7.1.js`, `jQuery.fn.load` in line 10191 suggests to me that `"html"` is the default `dataType`, and I only see 2 unrelated instances of `parseXML` (but I may be in over my head trying to decipher that). Perhaps it's something with Firefox?

Comment: Yes that would be 100% a Firefox thing: `const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("get", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`<html><br></html>`])));
x.send();` already outputs the same error in the console, even without accessing `responseXML`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I'm posting a solution to the first question, [given by @Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137708/console-is-throwing-xml-parsing-errors-when-loading-contents-from-one-html-file/78146707#comment137754898_78137708) (modified for clarity).

The XML Parsing Errors occurred when using this `<script>` for `updateContainer`:

```html
<script>
  function updateContainer(container, filename) {
    $(container).load(filename);
  }
</script>
```

The XML Parsing Errors stopped after redefining the function to explicitly parse the file as HTML instead of XML:

```html
<script>
  async function updateContainer(container, filename) {
    const response = await fetch(filename);
    const text = await response.text();
    $(container).html($.parseHTML(text));
  }
</script>
```